# ForEach - print both an item and numerical value

Tags: swift, swiftui

How can I achieve a ForEach result that displays each array member, along with numerical values depending on the list count, that increment up for each item

Example would be
1 "Turkey"
2 "Ham"
3 "Mayo"

```
struct EditorDirections: View {
    @State private var recipeDirections: [String] = ["Ham", "Turkey", "Mayo"]
   
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack{
            List{
                ForEach(recipeDirections, id: \.self){ recipe in
                    HStack{
                        Text()// show 1, 2, 3
                        Text(recipe)
                    }
                }
           }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try using enumerated

```
ForEach(Array(recipeDirections.enumerated()), id: \.offset){ (index,recipe) in
```

The index will be 0,1,2, according to array numbers.