# How to fix a crash in SwiftUI caused by UICollectionView _validateScrollingTargetIndexPath?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I'm working on a SwiftUI app. The app keeps crashing with the following error message:

**UIKitCore: - [UICollectionView _validateScrollingTargetIndexPath:] + 412**

I've checked the crash logs in Xcode's Organizer > App > Reports > Crashes section and found this to be the source of the problem, but I don't understand.

Can anyone help me understand what's causing this crash and how to fix it? I'd appreciate any guidance or advice on how to troubleshoot this issue.

Thanks in advance!

Crash Log:

````
Incident Identifier: B57CBB49-CE6A-4F79-AD15-C8A81B66A8AC
Hardware Model:      iPhone12,1
Process:             [APP_NAME] [42598]
Path:                /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/739BA0B9-3014-4384-AC60-6A96A30472F1/[APP_NAME].app/[APP_NAME]
Identifier:          -- --
Version:             1.0.7 (2)
AppStoreTools:       14C17
Code Type:           ARM-64 (Native)
Role:                Foreground
Parent Process:      launchd [1]
Coalition:           -- -- [2646]

Date/Time:           2023-03-16 18:50:43.5696 +0300
Launch Time:         2023-03-16 18:45:21.3862 +0300
OS Version:          iPhone OS 16.0.2 (20A380)
Release Type:        User
Baseband Version:    4.00.00
Report Version:      104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x0000000000000000, 0x0000000000000000
Triggered by Thread:  0

Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1c4d36248 __exceptionPreprocess + 164 (NSException.m:202)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1be103a68 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:356)
2   Foundation                      0x1bf6c281c -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 188 (NSException.m:242)
3   UIKitCore                       0x1c72a6e80 -[UICollectionView _validateScrollingTargetIndexPath:] + 412 (UICollectionView.m:0)
4   UIKitCore                       0x1c72a665c -[UICollectionView _contentOffsetForScrollingToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:] + 52 (UICollectionView.m:7348)
5   UIKitCore                       0x1c72a6078 -[UICollectionView _scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:] + 240 (UICollectionView.m:7563)
6   SwiftUI                         0x1c9045e38 PagingCollectionView.scrollToItem(at:at:animated:) + 320 (PageView_PhoneTV.swift:607)
7   SwiftUI                         0x1c9045f24 @objc PagingCollectionView.scrollToItem(at:at:animated:) + 208 (<compiler-generated>:0)
8   SwiftUI                         0x1c86b09dc PagingCollectionView.layoutSubviews() + 988 (PageView_PhoneTV.swift:595)
9   SwiftUI                         0x1c86af9e8 @objc PagingCollectionView.layoutSubviews() + 36 (<compiler-generated>:0)
10  UIKitCore                       0x1c6ebecec -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1980 (UIView.m:18550)
11  QuartzCore                      0x1c639b4e8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 500 (CALayer.mm:10223)
12  QuartzCore                      0x1c63aeb9c CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 148 (CALayer.mm:2516)
13  QuartzCore                      0x1c63c0098 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 456 (CAContextInternal.mm:2711)
14  QuartzCore                      0x1c63f73c4 CA::Transaction::commit() + 652 (CATransactionInternal.mm:431)
15  QuartzCore                      0x1c63de408 CA::Transaction::flush_as_runloop_observer(bool) + 88 (CATransactionInternal.mm:939)
16  CoreFoundation                  0x1c4dbe070 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 36 (CFRunLoop.c:1806)
17  CoreFoundation                  0x1c4d46690 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 532 (CFRunLoop.c:1919)
18  CoreFoundation                  0x1c4da7f8c __CFRunLoopRun + 1048 (CFRunLoop.c:2998)
19  CoreFoundation                  0x1c4dad1e4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612 (CFRunLoop.c:3390)
20  GraphicsServices                0x1fdbcd368 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2196)
21  UIKitCore                       0x1c725cd88 -[UIApplication _run] + 888 (UIApplication.m:3726)
22  UIKitCore                       0x1c725c9ec UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIApplication.m:5316)
23  SwiftUI                         0x1c885bce8 closure #1 in KitRendererCommon(_:) + 168 (UIKitApp.swift:37)
24  SwiftUI                         0x1c87b8c24 runApp<A>(_:) + 152 (<compiler-generated>:0)
25  SwiftUI                         0x1c87a1b44 static App.main() + 128 (App.swift:114)
26  [APP_NAME]                          0x10418bb94 static [APP_NAME]App.$main() + 52 ([APP_NAME]App.swift:14)
27  [APP_NAME]                          0x10418bb94 main + 64 (MainView.swift:0)
28  dyld                            0x1e30d1948 start + 2504 (dyldMain.cpp:1168)

Kernel Triage:
VM - pmap_enter retried due to resource shortage


Thread 0 name:
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020141e200 __pthread_kill + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021165b1ac pthread_kill + 268 (pthread.c:1670)
2   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001cc26d3f4 __abort + 128 (abort.c:155)
3   libsystem_c.dylib               0x00000001cc215cac abort + 192 (abort.c:126)
4   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000021159db8c abort_message + 132 (abort_message.cpp:78)
5   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000021158da80 demangling_terminate_handler() + 336 (cxa_default_handlers.cpp:71)
6   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001be109eec _objc_terminate() + 144 (objc-exception.mm:498)
7   [APP_NAME]                          0x000000010490cfd8 FIRCLSTerminateHandler() + 340 (FIRCLSException.mm:452)
8   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000021159cf28 std::__terminate(void (*)()) + 20 (cxa_handlers.cpp:59)
9   libc++abi.dylib                 0x000000021159fecc __cxa_rethrow + 148 (cxa_exception.cpp:616)
10  libobjc.A.dylib                 0x00000001be105854 objc_exception_rethrow + 44 (objc-exception.mm:401)
11  CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c4dad2a8 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 808 (CFRunLoop.c:3406)
12  GraphicsServices                0x00000001fdbcd368 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2196)
13  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c725cd88 -[UIApplication _run] + 888 (UIApplication.m:3726)
14  UIKitCore                       0x00000001c725c9ec UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIApplication.m:5316)
15  SwiftUI                         0x00000001c885bce8 closure #1 in KitRendererCommon(_:) + 168 (UIKitApp.swift:37)
16  SwiftUI                         0x00000001c87b8c24 runApp<A>(_:) + 152 (<compiler-generated>:0)
17  SwiftUI                         0x00000001c87a1b44 static App.main() + 128 (App.swift:114)
18  [APP_NAME]                          0x000000010418bb94 static [APP_NAME]App.$main() + 52 ([APP_NAME]App.swift:14)
19  [APP_NAME]                          0x000000010418bb94 main + 64 (MainView.swift:0)
20  dyld                            0x00000001e30d1948 start + 2504 (dyldMain.cpp:1168)

Thread 1 name:
Thread 1:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000201419480 kevent + 8 (:-1)
1   [APP_NAME]                          0x00000001044fdc84 realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::listen() + 160 (external_commit_helper.cpp:219)
2   [APP_NAME]                          0x00000001044fde64 realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&, realm::RealmConfig const&)::$_0::operator()() const + 4 (external_commit_helper.cpp:175)
3   [APP_NAME]                          0x00000001044fde64 decltype(static_cast<realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm::_impl::RealmCoordinator&, realm::RealmConfig const&)::$_0>(fp)()) std::__1::__invoke<realm::_impl::ExternalCommi... + 4 (type_traits:3918)
4   [APP_NAME]                          0x00000001044fde64 void std::__1::__thread_execute<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCommitHelper(realm... + 4 (thread:287)
5   [APP_NAME]                          0x00000001044fde64 void* std::__1::__thread_proxy<std::__1::tuple<std::__1::unique_ptr<std::__1::__thread_struct, std::__1::default_delete<std::__1::__thread_struct> >, realm::_impl::ExternalCommitHelper::ExternalCom... + 52 (thread:298)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002116556cc _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:893)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000211654ba4 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 2 name:
Thread 2:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000201417b48 mach_msg2_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020142a008 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020142a248 mach_msg_overwrite + 388 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020141808c mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   [APP_NAME]                          0x000000010490eb18 FIRCLSMachExceptionReadMessage + 60 (FIRCLSMachException.c:192)
5   [APP_NAME]                          0x000000010490eb18 FIRCLSMachExceptionServer + 108 (FIRCLSMachException.c:168)
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002116556cc _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:893)
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000211654ba4 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 3 name:
Thread 3:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000201417b48 mach_msg2_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020142a008 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020142a248 mach_msg_overwrite + 388 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020141808c mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c4da6e00 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160 (CFRunLoop.c:2639)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c4da8044 __CFRunLoopRun + 1232 (CFRunLoop.c:3022)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c4dad1e4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612 (CFRunLoop.c:3390)
7   Foundation                      0x00000001bf1bd818 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212 (NSRunLoop.m:373)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001bf1bd700 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runUntilDate:] + 64 (NSRunLoop.m:420)
9   UIKitCore                       0x00000001c739188c -[UIEventFetcher threadMain] + 436 (UIEventFetcher.m:1212)
10  Foundation                      0x00000001bf1d6ce8 __NSThread__start__ + 716 (NSThread.m:968)
11  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002116556cc _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:893)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000211654ba4 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 4 name:
Thread 4:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020141841c __psynch_cvwait + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x000000021165c06c _pthread_cond_wait + 1232 (pthread_cond.c:636)
2   JavaScriptCore                  0x00000001d811fc70 scavenger_thread_main + 1364 (pas_scavenger.c:145)
3   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002116556cc _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:893)
4   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000211654ba4 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 5 name:
Thread 5:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000201417b48 mach_msg2_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020142a008 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020142a248 mach_msg_overwrite + 388 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020141808c mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c4da6e00 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160 (CFRunLoop.c:2639)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c4da8044 __CFRunLoopRun + 1232 (CFRunLoop.c:3022)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c4dad1e4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612 (CFRunLoop.c:3390)
7   CFNetwork                       0x00000001c60fbbac +[__CFN_CoreSchedulingSetRunnable _run:] + 392 (CoreSchedulingSet.mm:1372)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001bf1d6ce8 __NSThread__start__ + 716 (NSThread.m:968)
9   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002116556cc _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:893)
10  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000211654ba4 thread_start + 8 (:-1)

Thread 6:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000211654b90 _pthread_cond_updateval + 256 (pthread_cond.c:992)

Thread 7:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000211654b90 _pthread_cond_updateval + 256 (pthread_cond.c:992)

Thread 8:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000211654b90 _pthread_cond_updateval + 256 (pthread_cond.c:992)

Thread 9:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000211654b90 _pthread_cond_updateval + 256 (pthread_cond.c:992)

Thread 10:
0   libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000211654b90 _pthread_cond_updateval + 256 (pthread_cond.c:992)

Thread 11 name:
Thread 11:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x0000000201417b48 mach_msg2_trap + 8 (:-1)
1   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020142a008 mach_msg2_internal + 80 (mach_msg.c:201)
2   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020142a248 mach_msg_overwrite + 388 (mach_msg.c:0)
3   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x000000020141808c mach_msg + 24 (mach_msg.c:323)
4   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c4da6e00 __CFRunLoopServiceMachPort + 160 (CFRunLoop.c:2639)
5   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c4da8044 __CFRunLoopRun + 1232 (CFRunLoop.c:3022)
6   CoreFoundation                  0x00000001c4dad1e4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612 (CFRunLoop.c:3390)
7   Foundation                      0x00000001bf1bd818 -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) runMode:beforeDate:] + 212 (NSRunLoop.m:373)
8   Foundation                      0x00000001bf1bd6ac -[NSRunLoop(NSRunLoop) run] + 64 (NSRunLoop.m:398)
9   SwiftUI                         0x00000001c872e558 static DisplayLink.asyncThread(arg:) + 800 (_UIHostingView.swift:965)
10  SwiftUI                         0x00000001c872c69c @objc static DisplayLink.asyncThread(arg:) + 88 (<compiler-generated>:0)
11  Foundation                      0x00000001bf1d6ce8 __NSThread__start__ + 716 (NSThread.m:968)
12  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x00000002116556cc _pthread_start + 148 (pthread.c:893)
13  libsystem_pthread.dylib         0x0000000211654ba4 thread_start + 8 (:-1)


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State (64-bit):
    x0: 0x0000000000000000   x1: 0x0000000000000000   x2: 0x0000000000000000   x3: 0x0000000000000000
    x4: 0x0000000000000000   x5: 0x0000000000989680   x6: 0x000000000000006e   x7: 0x0000000000000000
    x8: 0x2d9f778a7e9debb1   x9: 0x2d9f7788646d0831  x10: 0x00000000000003e8  x11: 0x000000000000000b
   x12: 0x000000000000000b  x13: 0x0000000000000000  x14: 0x0000000000000000  x15: 0x0000000000000000
   x16: 0x0000000000000148  x17: 0x000000021af0e380  x18: 0x0000000000000000  x19: 0x0000000000000006
   x20: 0x0000000000000103  x21: 0x000000021af0e460  x22: 0x0000000000000007  x23: 0x0000000104cdc8c8
   x24: 0x0000000000000000  x25: 0x0000000000000001  x26: 0x0000000000000001  x27: 0x0000000000000000
   x28: 0x00000001e59479e0   fp: 0x000000016bc7eed0   lr: 0x000000021165b1ac
    sp: 0x000000016bc7eeb0   pc: 0x000000020141e200 cpsr: 0x40000000
   esr: 0x56000080  Address size fault


Binary Images:
0x104180000 - 0x104e33fff [APP_NAME] arm64  <09be88e72ed73d15b5ead893c272fde9> /private/var/containers/Bundle/Application/739BA0B9-3014-4384-AC60-6A96A30472F1/[APP_NAME].app/[APP_NAME]
0x1be0ec000 - 0x1be12fc3f libobjc.A.dylib arm64e  <b3a78098c0fb3dcdb1ac0712762510db> /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib
0x1bf17c000 - 0x1bfac6fff Foundation arm64e  <aa92cd58561a341492f4b4120298b39a> /System/Library/Frameworks/Foundation.framework/Foundation
0x1c4d2c000 - 0x1c5110fff CoreFoundation arm64e  <42c5c91704473995b50fde4d132c2435> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/CoreFoundation
0x1c5ea7000 - 0x1c626cfff CFNetwork arm64e  <35605de33723335a83d96f35f2989935> /System/Library/Frameworks/CFNetwork.framework/CFNetwork
0x1c6391000 - 0x1c66e9fff QuartzCore arm64e  <c4c4667b69333b01a37b747cd0c00431> /System/Library/Frameworks/QuartzCore.framework/QuartzCore
0x1c6eba000 - 0x1c8680fff UIKitCore arm64e  <7b942fa4cb7633759972f58c14492fb4> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/UIKitCore.framework/UIKitCore
0x1c8681000 - 0x1c9ec9fff SwiftUI arm64e  <122e646e6b173561975fc414c8dae3d3> /System/Library/Frameworks/SwiftUI.framework/SwiftUI
0x1cc1f5000 - 0x1cc274fff libsystem_c.dylib arm64e  <82c0f938e2773165a61470151c651798> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib
0x1d802c000 - 0x1d9503fff JavaScriptCore arm64e  <9f4a8d8984473fa5a2e388d3c7ba1684> /System/Library/Frameworks/JavaScriptCore.framework/JavaScriptCore
0x1e30bc000 - 0x1e313ee4f dyld arm64e  <341bbf646034357e8aa6e1e4b988e03c> /usr/lib/dyld
0x1fdbcc000 - 0x1fdbd4fff GraphicsServices arm64e  <03732ba5113235b4b09d8dd49807d246> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/GraphicsServices.framework/GraphicsServices
0x201417000 - 0x20144dffb libsystem_kernel.dylib arm64e  <a5d3b72578c33e19a765cceb22355093> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
0x21158c000 - 0x2115a3ffb libc++abi.dylib arm64e  <e0dbf9459cc5305db096abc1cda9c8ca> /usr/lib/libc++abi.dylib
0x211654000 - 0x21165ffff libsystem_pthread.dylib arm64e  <b89b9a5b55d93e84b6d3c3da93c1cd39> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib

EOF

```
````

Comment: I have the same issue. I am unable to reproduce but I see this crash log multiple times a day in Xcode organizer windows crashes list. Were you able to fix it? Users with 16.0-16.3 OS are getting this issue.

Comment: Unfortunately I couldn't fix it. But since most of my users switched to iOS 17, I had to ignore it.

Answer (score 1):

it seems iOS 16.0 bug. try update OS.

[Simple TabView is crashing in iOS 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73950003/simple-tabview-is-crashing-in-ios-16)

Comment: Wow. That's really unfortunate because even though users complain about crashes, it's really difficult to direct them towards a system update. Thank you.