# How to get more info from a SwiftUI crashlytics error

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, crashlytics

I have migrated an iOS app from UIKit to SwiftUI. I have recently released the SwiftUI version and yesterday Crashlytics reported a crash that I don't know how to fix because I have no idea where the crash is happening.

The crash report says this:

```
_userInfoForFileAndLine
NSInternalInconsistencyException - attempt to insert item 268 into section 0, but there are only 0 items in section 0 after the update

 Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
Attempted to scroll the collection view to an out-of-bounds item (0) when there are only 0 items in section 0. Collection view: <_TtC7SwiftUIP33_8825076C2763A50452A210CBE1FA4AF020PagingCollectionView: 0x1238fd000; baseClass = UICollectionView; frame = (0 0; 340 105); clipsToBounds = YES; autoresize = W+H; gestureRecognizers = <NSArray: 0x2838f89f0>; backgroundColor = UIExtendedGrayColorSpace 0 0; layer = <CALayer: 0x2836c2cc0>; contentOffset: {0, 0}; contentSize: {0, 0}; adjustedContentInset: {0, 0, 0, 0}; layout: <_TtC7SwiftUIP33_8825076C2763A50452A210CBE1FA4AF012PagingLayout: 0x12268c400>; dataSource: (null)>.


Fatal Exception: NSInternalInconsistencyException
0  CoreFoundation                 0xa248 __exceptionPreprocess
1  libobjc.A.dylib                0x17a68 objc_exception_throw
2  Foundation                     0x54681c _userInfoForFileAndLine
3  UIKitCore                      0x3ece80 -[UICollectionView _validateScrollingTargetIndexPath:]
4  UIKitCore                      0x3ec65c -[UICollectionView _contentOffsetForScrollingToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:]
5  UIKitCore                      0x3ec078 -[UICollectionView _scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:]
6  SwiftUI                        0x9c4e38 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_17
7  SwiftUI                        0x9c4f24 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_17
8  SwiftUI                        0x2f9dc OUTLINED_FUNCTION_173
9  SwiftUI                        0x2e9e8 OUTLINED_FUNCTION_504
10 UIKitCore                      0x4cec -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:]
11 QuartzCore                     0xa4e8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
12 QuartzCore                     0x1db9c CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*)
13 QuartzCore                     0x2f098 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*)
14 QuartzCore                     0x663c4 CA::Transaction::commit()
15 UIKitCore                      0x49431c __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2
16 CoreFoundation                 0x43924 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__
17 CoreFoundation                 0xac0ac __CFRunLoopDoBlocks
18 CoreFoundation                 0x7becc __CFRunLoopRun
19 CoreFoundation                 0x811e4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific
20 GraphicsServices               0x1368 GSEventRunModal
21 UIKitCore                      0x3a2d88 -[UIApplication _run]
22 UIKitCore                      0x3a29ec UIApplicationMain
23 MySwiftUIApp                   0xf0e4 main + 14 (main.m:14)
24 ???                            0x1ca3d1948 (Missing)
```

The only mention to MySwiftUIApp is the line main + 14 (main.m:14) (not much information).

But what is more strange to me, the problem seems to happen in a UICollectionView, but I don't have any UICollectionView in my app!

All of them where removed from the UIKit app and replaced for List swiftUI views.
Could these Lists call at a low level to a UIKit UICollectionView? I don't think so...

I was thinking in add crashlytics logs to every List in my app to see what's happening in case this crash happens again, but I'm not sure if this is a good idea.

One last thing: these errors have happened 3 times to the same user and the crash times have been Sep 19, 2023, 9:01:41 AM , Sep 19, 2023, 9:01:43 AM and Sep 19, 2023, 9:01:45 AM. How is this possible? how could a crash happens 3 times in 3 seconds? is this a "problem" of Crashlytics?

I would like to add some code, but I have no idea which class, view or file is crashing.

Any clue will be very appreciated!

Comment: SwiftUI sits on top of UIKit, so yes, a SwiftUI List is just a UICollectionView

Comment: [This might be helpful](https://www.emergetools.com/blog/posts/symbolicating-swiftui-and-any-apple-framework). And yeah, SwiftUI is implemented on top of UIKit, and various types like `List` use `UICollectionView` under the hood.

Comment: Thank you both! I didn't know about XCode organizer crashes reports, it's very interesting. But unfortunately, for this crash, it shows the same stacktrace as Crashlytics but without the swiftui steps, so I don't have any clue yet. I will study your link.

Answer (score 1):

Well, thanks to dalton_c comment, I've managed to get a stacktrace with clear messages for SwiftUI steps:

```
Last Exception Backtrace:
0   CoreFoundation                  0x1aa82e248 __exceptionPreprocess + 164 (NSException.m:202)
1   libobjc.A.dylib                 0x1a3bf3a68 objc_exception_throw + 60 (objc-exception.mm:356)
2   Foundation                      0x1a51b281c -[NSAssertionHandler handleFailureInMethod:object:file:lineNumber:description:] + 188 (NSException.m:242)
3   UIKitCore                       0x1acd9ee80 -[UICollectionView _validateScrollingTargetIndexPath:] + 412 (UICollectionView.m:0)
4   UIKitCore                       0x1acd9e65c -[UICollectionView _contentOffsetForScrollingToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:] + 52 (UICollectionView.m:7348)
5   UIKitCore                       0x1acd9e078 -[UICollectionView _scrollToItemAtIndexPath:atScrollPosition:animated:] + 240 (UICollectionView.m:7563)
6   SwiftUI                         0x1aeb3de38 PagingCollectionView.scrollToItem(at:at:animated:) + 320 (PageView_PhoneTV.swift:607)
7   SwiftUI                         0x1aeb3df24 @objc PagingCollectionView.scrollToItem(at:at:animated:) + 208 (<compiler-generated>:0)
8   SwiftUI                         0x1ae1a89dc PagingCollectionView.layoutSubviews() + 988 (PageView_PhoneTV.swift:595)
9   SwiftUI                         0x1ae1a79e8 @objc PagingCollectionView.layoutSubviews() + 36 (<compiler-generated>:0)
10  UIKitCore                       0x1ac9b6cec -[UIView(CALayerDelegate) layoutSublayersOfLayer:] + 1980 (UIView.m:18550)
11  QuartzCore                      0x1abe934e8 CA::Layer::layout_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 500 (CALayer.mm:10223)
12  QuartzCore                      0x1abea6b9c CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 148 (CALayer.mm:2516)
13  QuartzCore                      0x1abeb8098 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*, double, double*) + 456 (CAContextInternal.mm:2711)
14  QuartzCore                      0x1abeef3c4 CA::Transaction::commit() + 652 (CATransactionInternal.mm:431)
15  UIKitCore                       0x1ace4631c __34-[UIApplication _firstCommitBlock]_block_invoke_2 + 36 (UIApplication.m:12109)
16  CoreFoundation                  0x1aa867924 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 28 (CFRunLoop.c:1822)
17  CoreFoundation                  0x1aa8d00ac __CFRunLoopDoBlocks + 368 (CFRunLoop.c:1864)
18  CoreFoundation                  0x1aa89fecc __CFRunLoopRun + 856 (CFRunLoop.c:2972)
19  CoreFoundation                  0x1aa8a51e4 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 612 (CFRunLoop.c:3390)
20  GraphicsServices                0x1e36c5368 GSEventRunModal + 164 (GSEvent.c:2196)
21  UIKitCore                       0x1acd54d88 -[UIApplication _run] + 888 (UIApplication.m:3726)
22  UIKitCore                       0x1acd549ec UIApplicationMain + 340 (UIApplication.m:5316)
23  MySwiftUIApp                    0x100feb0e4 main + 80 (main.m:14)
24  dyld                            0x1c8bc9948 start + 2504 (dyldMain.cpp:1168)
```

And I've made a new searh in StackOverflow related to line 8: "PageView_PhoneTV".

And I've found this:

[How to fix a crash in SwiftUI caused by UICollectionView _validateScrollingTargetIndexPath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75927099/how-to-fix-a-crash-in-swiftui-caused-by-uicollectionview-validatescrollingtarge)

and this:

[Simple TabView is crashing in iOS 16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73950003/simple-tabview-is-crashing-in-ios-16)

Taking into account that the user is using iOS 16.0, it seems that this answer my question, and its related to my TabView, and it's a iOS 16.0 bug.

Comment: for the symbolication did you get that via Xcode's Organizer or were you somehow able to resymbolicate the Crashlytics logs using the EmergeTools blog? Trying to symbolicate a SwiftUI crash seen in Crashlytics but not yet in Xcode reporting and was curious what you ended up doing to get symbolicated.