# SwiftUI ForEach Throws out of index error

Tags: swiftui, foreach

I cant seem to understand why this can throw an error?
The first for each loop is working perfectly, 2nd is throwing an error.
I need to use index of the array to get custom colors for my code. Otherwise i would go with normal ForEach.

```
    @ViewBuilder
    private func chartLegendView() -> some View {
        if !viewModel.topTransactions.isEmpty {
            VStack {
                ForEach(viewModel.topTransactions, id: \.self) { transaction in
                    Text(transaction.description)
                }
                ForEach(viewModel.topTransactions.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                    Text(viewModel.topTransactions[index].description)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

[image]

I have tried all the logical options, but nothing works.

UPDATE 1: This is what I am trying to achieve.
Im getting an array of transactions from SwiftData.
I am creating a custom object from that array of transactions (grouping by category and some other calculations) and displaying them in a SwiftUI Chart. What I have is that my Chart legend and Chart colors are custom.

I have predefined 10 colors to be used on the chart in an array. That's why I use an index to grab a color from each item In the chart.

My user can choose "Income, Expense, or date" to filter the data coming from SwiftData and regenerate the UI. I do agree that the problem looks like a model/fetching issue.

this is how I have "solved" the problem, but its wrong. I still have crashes when filters change.

```
@ViewBuilder
private func chartLegendView() -> some View {
    VStack {
        ForEach(Array(viewModel.topTransactions.prefix(analyticsTransactionsNumber).enumerated()), id: \.element) { index, transaction in
            TopExpenseRow(topExpense: transaction, color: categoryColors[index])

        }
    }
}

struct TopTransaction: Comparable, Hashable, Identifiable {
let id = UUID()
let total: Double
let percentOfTotal: Double
let category: Category?

var description: String {
    "\(name) \(percentOfTotal.noDecimalString)%"
}

var name: String {
    category?.name ?? "Unknown"
}

static func < (lhs: TopTransaction, rhs: TopTransaction) -> Bool {
    return lhs.total > rhs.total
}

func hash(into hasher: inout Hasher) {
    hasher.combine(id)
    hasher.combine(name)
    hasher.combine(total)
    hasher.combine(percentOfTotal)
}
```

}

[image]

Comment: Index is unsafe in a ForEach you shouldn’t use it. But enumerated seems a bit more stable

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72222014/foreach-print-both-an-item-and-numerical-value/72222051#72222051

Comment: Don't use `index` especially with an unrelated array there is no way to tell SwiftUI there is a change prepare your data before you get to the `ForEach`

Answer (score 1):

Your `@ViewBuilder` function looks fine, the issue is in your data model. I can't assume the solution without looking into your model structure but here is a sample of `forEach` similar to yours that works with and without indices.

```
struct Thing: Hashable {
  var name: String
  init(_ name: String) {
    self.name = name
  }
}

struct Test: View {
  @State var data = [Thing("A"), Thing("B"), Thing("C"), Thing("D"), Thing("E"), Thing("F")]
  @ViewBuilder
  private func chartLegendView() -> some View {
    VStack {
      ForEach(data, id: \.self) { thing in
        Text(thing.name)
      }
      ForEach(data.indices, id: \.self) { index in
        Text(data[index].name)
      }
    }
  }
  var body: some View {
    chartLegendView()
  }
}
```

[image]

Unless the data source is static it's best not to use index as it holds strong a reference to the collection.

[image]

Comment: Index is unsafe “Demystify SwiftUI” attributes this error to that

Comment: That's true, unless data source is static it's best not to use index.

Comment: And in your case since the array is in a State it isn’t static

Comment: I have updated the question with extra info. I do agree that the issue is more of a model thing. I am guessing the best option would be adding the color directly to my custom TopTransaction object and use normal ForEachLoop

Comment: thank you @Yasha for your answer. I updated my initial question

Answer (score -2):

Lots of mistakes:

1. Remove `@ViewBuilder`, that is what `View` and `body` is for, so make a new custom `ChartLegendView`.
2. Remove `if`, this generates a `_ConditionalView` which is unnecessary in your code.
3. Remove `id: \.self`, you need real ids with `ForEach`, or better to make your model struct conform to identifiable.
4. Don't use indices or accessing an array by index inside a ForEach's closure. Indices are not unique across changes, e.g. a transaction at index 0 will get id 0 which is the same as any other transaction at index 0 so it couldn't detect the deletion of a transaction at index 0 when there are multiple transactions, you need to use real ids.

So it should look like this:

```
struct ChartLegendView: View {

    let transactions: [Transaction]
    var body: View {    
        ForEach(transactions) { transaction in
             Text(transaction.description)
        }
    }
}

struct Transaction: Identifiable {
    var id: String {
        return a unique combination of vars, e.g. user + transactionID
    }
...
```